# BigDecimal to Currency with -0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bigdecimal, zero, number-to-currency

I am working on reports for a website and I am currently thinking of what would be the best way to handle BigDecimal -0.0's.

The database I'm working with has a lot of them. When these -0.0's are put through `number_to_currency()`, I get "$-0.00". My format for negative numbers is actually "-$x.xx", so note that number_to_currency is not formatting it as a negative number (otherwise there would also be a negative sign in front of the dollar sign), but for some reason the negative sign is being translated along with the 0.

Right now my solution is to do this every time I get an amount from the database:

```
amount *= -1 if amount == 0 && amount.sign == -1
```

This changes the -0.0 to a 0.0. It's simple enough, but I can't help but wonder if there is a better solution, or something on BigDecimals or number_to_currency to handle this situation that I'm just not finding.

Comment: What calculation are you doing to store $-0.0 in your database?  When I do `(BigDecimal.new("50.00") + BigDecimal.new("-50.00")).zero?` I get `true`

Comment: @Anthony - I don't know how the -0.0 is stored in the database. I'm working with a database I didn't create, buy my next step will be to investigate this. If I can avoid storing it, it will save me a lot of work. Otherwise, Syed has given me a pretty thorough answer and a nicer way to write my solution.

Comment: If you have any say, I'd talk to the team, write a migration to convert all the -0.0 to 0.0 in the database and then not have to worry about any of this view logic.  Obviously that requires you store it correctly in the db going forward too.

Comment: @Anthony - It was being stored fine as 0.0, but one of the models applied a *-1 if the transaction was of type 'CREDIT'. I've added a check in the method to first see if it is .zero? All of my "$-0.00"s are gone now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is so because the number is converted into a string to be displayed. And:

```
# to_d converts to BigDecimal, just FYI
"-0".to_d.to_s #=> "-0.0"
```

Therefore you will have to make it a 0 yourself. But the sign-checks are redundant - a simple comparison with 0 will do the trick:

```
bdn = "-0".to_d # or BigDecimal.new("-0")
value = bdn.zero? ? 0 : bdn
number_to_currency(value, other_options)
```

However, you wouldn't want to manually add this check everywhere you're calling `number_to_currency`. It would be more convenient to create your own `modified_number_to_currency` method, in your ApplicationHelper, like so:

```
def modified_number_to_currency( number, options )
  value = number.zero? ? 0 : number
  number_to_currency(value, options)
end
```

And then use `modified_number_to_currency` instead of `number_to_currency`.

Alternatively, you could overwrite `number_to_currency` and have it call `super` in the end. That *might* also work but I'm not 100% certain.

Coming to your check specifically:

```
amount *= -1 if amount == 0 && amount.sign == -1
```

It should simply be:

```
amount = 0.to_d if amount.zero? # the to_d might or might not be required
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you. You confirmed a lot of the stuff that I was thinking and made my check even better. And the .to_d is not required. I am going to try and investigate how these BigDecimals are being stored in the database and hopefully I can avoid storing -0's. That would avoid the need for a check altogether.

Comment: It was being stored fine as 0.0, but one of the models applied a *-1 if the transaction was of type 'CREDIT'. I've added a check in the method to first see if it is .zero? All of my "$-0.00"s are gone now :)

Comment: When using `modified_number_to_currency` it is good to keep the default options of `options = {}` or one may run into troubles when no options are given.